# How to convert a web html to pdf with pyqt5

Tags: html, pdf, pyqt5

last year i converted html to pdf with pyqt4 succesfully.. but with pyqt5 i lost 2 days and i´m frustrated..

This is my code:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication 
from PyQt5.QtWebKitWidgets import QWebView
from PyQt5.QtPrintSupport import QPrinter
from PyQt5.QtCore import  QUrl

app = QApplication(sys.argv)

web = QWebView()
web.load(QUrl("https://www.google.com"))
printer = QPrinter()
printer.setPageSize(QPrinter.A4)
printer.setOutputFormat(QPrinter.PdfFormat)
printer.setOutputFileName("out.pdf")

def convertIt():
    web.print_(printer)
    print ('Pdf generado')
    QApplication.exit()

QObject.connect(web, SIGNAL("loadFinished(bool)"), convertIt)
app.exec_()
```

And i have one "QOject no have attribute "connect"...   i know is something about the signals, that changed from pyqt4 to pyqt5, but i have no idea to code it.. thanks in advance.

Comment: `import sys` is missing from the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be `web.loadFinished.connect(convertIt)` as per the [PyQt docs about signals/slots](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt5/signals_slots.html#connecting-disconnecting-and-emitting-signals).

Comment: solved... sorry again :)) all fine!!  i put web.load(QUrl("url")) and i should put web.load(QUrl(url)), i novice error..